# Associate another filename extension with existing UTI

Tags: finder, uti, launch-services

The macOS system recognizes various files as JavaScript. If the filename extension is `.js`, `.jscript`, `.javascript` or `.mjs`, the file's Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) is `com.netscape.javascript-source` and the file is considered to be JavaScript. This list of filename extensions is 'hard-coded' in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`, where that UTI is defined in a dictionary entry with this subkey:

```xml
<key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
<dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <array>
        <string>js</string>
        <string>jscript</string>
        <string>javascript</string>
        <string>mjs</string>
    </array>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <array>
        <string>text/javascript</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I would like to add another filename extension to the set that identifies JavaScript files on my Mac. The extension `.jsm` is often used with the same meaning as `.mjs`, a JavaScript module. For example, the source code of Firefox has 484 `jsm` files and the source code of Thunderbird has 429. If they could have that same UTI, it would become easier to work with them – for example, they'd be treated the same by Quicklook.

Is this possible? Can you override the built-in UTI definition, or somehow add something to it? Editing this system file seems unwise (and will have to be repeated after every OS update). I tried doing it in the `Info.plist` of an ad-hoc Automator application, and then importing that app with `lsregister`, but have so far had no luck. My question is similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24373/how-can-i-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-content-type), but more specific.