# icon for iTunes 10.7/music missing from System Preferences in Snow Leopard

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard, icon, system-settings

My music/iTunes icon:

- is present in the Dock
- has gone from some panes of System Preferences.

This first screenshot is from the Spotlight pane, the icon is expected to the left of `Music`:

[image: Spotlight preferences]

The second shot is from the CDs & DVDs pane, the icon is expected to the left of `Open iTunes`:

[image: CD&DVD]

How do I get these icons back?

System:

- MacBook Pro
- Snow Leopard 10.6.8

What I tried:

- reboot
- login/logout
- trash Finder and Dock preference files

---

Edit 1:

The output of the `grep` command suggested by Graham Perrin in the comments is as follows:

```
Laptop:~ myname$ system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | grep iTunes.app  
      Location: /Applications/iTunes.app
```

In the Language & Text pane, three languages are present in the following order:

- British English
- Dutch
- Russian

Logging into a fresh user account does not solve the issue. The same icon is missing in the same places.

---

Edit 2: Output for command `/usr/bin/mdimport -L`

```
Laptop:~ myname$ /usr/bin/mdimport -L 2012-10-24 11:12:32.307
mdimport[34295:903] Paths: id(501) (
    "/Library/Spotlight/iWork.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Font.mdimporter",
    "/Library/Spotlight/Microsoft Office.mdimporter",
    "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/SourceCode.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Archives.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Audio.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/ParallelsMD.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Image.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Application.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/SPSS/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/SPSSSpotlightImporter.mdimporter",
    "/Library/Spotlight/AppleWorks.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/RichText.mdimporter",
    "/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/MZSpotlight.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/OmniGraffle Professional 5.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/OmniGraffle.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/CoreMedia.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/Sente 6.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/Sente6MI.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Chat.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/iPhoto.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/PS.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Mail.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/vCard.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/PDF.mdimporter",
    "/Library/Spotlight/GBSpotlightImporter.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/iPhoto8.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Bookmarks.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/DVIImporter.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/SystemPrefs.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/iCal.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/MIDI.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/QuartzComposer.mdimporter",
    "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Google Earth for Plugin.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/Google Earth.mdimporter",
    "/System/Library/Spotlight/Automator.mdimporter",
    "/Users/b8i/Library/Spotlight/EndNote.mdimporter",
    "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/uuid.mdimporter"
)
```

---

Edit 3: Although the bounty has run out I still don't have a solution for this problem.

---

Edit 4:
I have been poking around and through the "Open Files and Ports" function of the Activity Monitor I think I found the location where the images are loaded from. The file is:

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ArtFile.bin

Unfortunately I cannot open this file. Does anyone know how to open the file to see if that is the place where the images are loaded from?
When I rename `Artfile.bin` almost no application starts.

---

Edit 5:

The Garageband application *does* show the iTunes icon:
[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the icon for iTunes in the past?

Comment: No, I did not change the iTunes icon.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin I've added the requested information to my question.

Comment: I'll be tracking this. I have the *exact* same problem, and have even reinstalled 10.6.8 (for something else, not this) along the way, with no change. It started when I updated iTunes to 10.6.3 a few months ago. It took several tries to get the update to install, and when it finally went through - no icon in several places throughout the system. Good luck.

Comment: @soxman if you have the `install.log` files from that period, you could ask a separate (linked) question: *Why did installations of iTunes 10.6.3 fail?*

Comment: @GrahamPerrin I've added the output, thank you for your active help with this question.

Comment: By the way, I have iTunes 10.7, not 10.6.3. Does that matter for the question title?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin unfortunately my HDD wipe and reinstall took place in between now and then. I have installed 10.8.2 on another partition (same HDD), however, and I can confirm that the iTunes icon is present. This was a migration from the 10.6.8 partition, though iTunes has been updated to 10.7 for both OSes. Super weird, so it must be some system-wide issue specific to 10.6.x running a busted install of iTunes 10.6.3 and higher.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake with the title - now corrected. (I had 10.6.3 in mind after reading Dock-related topics such as [missing itunes icon - MacRumors Forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1385338).\)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although reinstalling iTunes did not help, updating did. I just downloaded iTunes 11 and now all icons are back where they should be.

Answer (score 2):

By reinstalling iTunes, did you completely trash the application and then copy it anew?  Sometimes simply overwriting the existing installation doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I used TrashMe to remove iTunes. Then I downloaded iTunes again from the iTunes website.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall iTunes.  The icons in the Spotlight preference window and other areas of OSX are mostly derived from the application bundle.  It looks like the iTunes icon package has become corrupted.  A reinstall will eliminate that as the reason.

Comment: Reinstalled iTunes, restarted, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ToolbarMusicFolderIcon.icns:
```

into terminal.app to see if ToolbarMusicFolderIcon.ics exists.

If not, [here is my copy.](http://cl.ly/1y453g3z0I2q) Download it and place it in:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/
```

Comment: That's not the right icon. On my system, both of the OP's missing icons are the iTunes app icon, not that one.

Comment: That's indeed not the icon I'm looking for, but I also don't have the file if I use the command in Terminal.

Comment: Oh :( sorry about that then

Comment: That's also the wrong command. The icns file is not executable, so it will fail on any system. What you probably mean is `sudo ls ...`.

Comment: Actually it's not really a command, that's the point.. it'll either say if it's a file, a directory or that no such file/directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [resetting Launch Services](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/resetlaunchservices.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it following the steps given in the link and unfortunately it did not solve my problem.

Comment: For recent versions of the OS, it's necessary to restart the OS (the article by *The X Lab* does not mention this). [Why is a command line change to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist not effective immediately?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/50004/8546) Consider disconnecting all backup volumes before and throughout the routine.

Comment: I have restarted after the launch service reset.