# Change file association in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

Is there a method for associating file types with applications via terminal? I thought ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.plist might do it, and I also have seen: [Why is a command line change to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist not effective immediately?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/why-is-a-command-line-change-to-library-preferences-com-apple-launchservices-p) but I can't seem to get it working.

I guess I'm looking for a way to imitate what the GUI does when someone uses it to change association types, it seems to work instantly there...

Comment: Has anyone had success lately [using xattr to change this on a file by file basis](https://superuser.com/a/1254271/76395)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` on Catalina) in a text editor after converting it to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
# Catalina: 
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist -o output.xml
```

Then add entries like this to the `LSHandlers` array:

```
<dict>
  <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
  <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
  <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim</string>
</dict>
<dict>
  <key>LSHandlerContentTag</key>
  <string>mkv</string>
  <key>LSHandlerContentTagClass</key>
  <string>public.filename-extension</string>
  <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>org.videolan.vlc</string>
</dict>
```

You can use `mdls` to see the UTIs of file types and something like `osascript -e 'id of app "AppName"'` to see the bundle identifiers of applications.

You can apply changes to `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` by restarting. Logging out and back in isn't enough.

---

> **NOTE**: `duti` is no longer in active development and has been labeled by its maintainers as "unsupported". The project hasn't seen any major progress since 2012 aside from configuration updates. It has moved from Sourceforge to Github. This answer has been updated to include the new links.

I also use [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti) though. I have saved a file like this (with about 100 lines) as `~/.duti`:

```
org.gnu.Emacs public.plain-text all # .txt, .text, plain text files without an extension
org.gnu.Emacs public.unix-executable all # executable scripts
com.SequentialX.Sequential .jpg all
org.videolan.vlc .mkv all
```

I have a launchd agent that runs `duti ~/.duti` automatically when `~/.duti` is changed.

You can normally use filename extensions (like `.jpg`) instead of a UTIs (like `public.jpg`) to specify file types. `duti` converts the extensions to UTIs that also apply to other extensions (like `.jpeg`). For some extensions like `.mkv` and `.tex`, the UTI depends on what application registered the extension first.

The [latest version](https://github.com/moretension/duti/releases) of `duti` only includes source code, but [1.5.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duti/files/duti/duti-1.5.0/) also includes an installer.

Comment: `duti` is well maintained as I see it. There is nowadays also a shell wrapper which helps to associate the applications very well, it's linked in the README of duti. `duti` + `dutis` rocks :))

Answer (score 11):

Check out [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti):

> duti is a command-line tool written by Andrew Mortensen, designed to set default applications for document types and URL schemes on Mac OS X.
>
> Document types on Mac OS X are defined by what Apple calls Uniform Type Identifiers, or UTIs. HTML files, for example, have a UTI of public.html. Microsoft Word documents are described by the UTI com.microsoft.word.doc. Apple provides many UTIs with Mac OS X, but developers are free to define their own, as long as the UTI is unique to that document type.
>
> duti's name means "default for UTI."

Comment: Mandatory suggestion: use `brew install duti` to install `duti`

Comment: Use, for example, `osascript -e 'id of app "Visual Studio Code"'` to get the bundle ID of an application. Also, `man duti` shows the manual page for duti.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a launchd agent for duti that will do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.duti.watcher</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/duti</string>
      <string>/Users/joshgummersall/.duti</string>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>joshgummersall</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/joshgummersall/.duti</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Obviously replace `joshgummersall` with your own username. I placed this file at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/duti.plist`, `chmmod`d to 644 and ran:

```
$ launchctl load -F -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/duti.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: A file's application association is stored in the file's *resource fork*, and Apple provides two utilities (*Rez* and *DeRez*) which allow manipulation of resource forks., but this is not for the faint of heart.

For more details, this question is answered very thoroughly at Super User:

- https://superuser.com/questions/259248

Comment: Nowadays, it's in an extended attribute (xattr) named `com.apple.LaunchServices.OpenWith`