# How to open shell scripts in editor when double clicking on them

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, bash, command-line

I'm trying to migrate to OS X. One thing what I find really strange / dangerous that by double clicking on shell scripts, I launch them in Terminal.

I would like to change this behaviour to open them in Sublime Text.

My problem is that while I can do it to single files using the "Get Info" dialog, I cannot apply "Change All..." for these kind of files.

For other filetypes it worked OK, but for .sh / Unix Executable File I cannot assign them.

When I click, I get the following error dialog:
The operation can't be completed.
An unexpected error occurred (error code -50).

Comment: I don't know why you are getting error code -50, I tried it on my system and it worked perfectly fine.

Look at this post to use Terminal to do it: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91558/49601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [duti](http://duti.org/documentation.html) by running `brew install duti`, save a file like

```
com.apple.TextEdit public.unix-executable all
```

as `~/.duti`, and then run `/usr/local/bin/duti ~/.duti`. After that executable scripts with no filename extension should be opened in TextEdit.

Another option is to run `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`, open the plist in a text editor, add an entry like

```
<dict>
  <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
  <string>public.unix-executable</string>
  <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>com.apple.TextEdit</string>
</dict>
```

under `LSHandlers`, and then restart to apply the changes.

The default application for shell scripts with a `.sh` extension can be changed from Finder:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the button which didn't work for me (error code -50). But duti works fine.