# set custom file extension to open with specified program

Tags: terminal, file

I want to have all files with an extension of .fw.png to open in Fireworks (not necessarily .png files though).

Is there a way to do this in Terminal?

Comment: Right click the file and choose open with (this will set for all applications) will not work for you?

Comment: He said in Terminal. If that's what he  wants, then we'll give him that. As for why, some people are geeks (like me ;D)

Comment: Lee, check out these threads: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91522/change-file-association-in-terminal and http://superuser.com/questions/259248/mac-osx-change-file-association-per-file-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. OS X file types ignore strings before the final .

You could rename all files x.fw.png to x.fw_png and then map that file type to FireWorks using many existing answers here but totally reprogramming how the OS parses for file extensions would be a hard nut to crack.

Answer (score 0):

If others search for how to change the default application for a normal extension like `.png`, you can use [duti](http://duti.org/documentation.html):

```
brew install duti;echo com.macromedia.fireworks .png all>~/.duti;/usr/local/bin/duti ~/.duti
```