# Set SublimText 3 as default app for files without extension

Tags: macos

Files without extension always open in TextEdit ...
I want them to open in SublimText 3

I tried to change my `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`, but simply adding `public.text` did not work ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was doing it with `public.data`

1. Go to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices`
2. Open `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` with Xcode
3. Add this :

[image: screen]

4. Save & Reboot

---

**Another way** to do it

- **Without Xcode**
- Working on macOS Mojave
- With Sublime Text 4

1. Convert binary plist to xml plist (for easy editing)

```
plutil \
-convert xml1 \
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist \
-o ~/Desktop/plist.xml
```

2. Open `plist.xml` (on your Desktop) with Sublime Text

Add inside `<array>`

```
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerContentType</key>
    <string>public.data</string>
    <key>LSHandlerPreferredVersions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
        <string>-</string>
    </dict>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.sublimetext.4</string>
</dict>
```

3. Convert back from XML to binary plist

```
plutil \
-convert binary1 \
~/Desktop/plist.xml \
-o ~/Desktop/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
```

4. Move the new `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`, from your Desktop to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/`

```
mv ~/Desktop/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist \
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/
```

5. Reboot

You can also use Sublime package `Plist Binary` or `BinaryPlist` instead of manually converting from binary to XML

Comment: A `.plist` file can be edited with any text editor, such as *SublimeText*, for instance! ;)

Comment: @Thecafremo, The `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` file is a binary plist file and while Sublime Text _can_ open it, it does so in hex mode and as such cannot be edited in the manner proposed in this answer. If it was an XML plist file, then it could.

Comment: @user3439894 Weird. *TextMate* will open it, and make it readable, without a problem.

Comment: @Thecafremo, I have Sublime Text 2, so maybe they improved it in version 3.

Comment: Nope. Sublime 3 still opens it in hex mode :/

Comment: @Thecafremo You can run plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist to edit it in Sublime or Vim.  [Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91558)

Comment: There's a Sublime package called `BinaryPlist` that does automatic conversion between binary and plain text.

Answer (score 3):

Copy paste script (working with catalina):

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.3;}' '{LSHandlerContentType=public.unix-executable;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.3;}'
```

This sets the default to `Sublime Text 3`. If you want to have any other app you have to simply replace `com.sublimetext.3` with the app id of your favorite app.