# How to open .cfg and .tex files with different applications on macOS?

Tags: macos, finder, applications, big-sur, plist

Every time I try to change the default application to open `.cfg` files, all `.tex` files are automatically set to be opened with the same application, and vice-versa.
This is problematic since I would like to open `.cfg` files with TextEdit and `.tex` files with Texpad.
Is there a way to do this ?

I don't know what causes this behavior, here's what I already tried:

- Set various editors as default app using [the standard method](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/choose-an-app-to-open-a-file-on-mac-mh35597/11.0/mac/11.0) (File > Get Info > Open With > Change All). I tried with TextEdit, Textmate, Atom, Texpad on both types of files.
- Set default app [using duti](https://superuser.com/a/1092184).
- Edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` to manually add entries then restart, as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91558/416482). The entries I edited are the following:

  ```
  {  LSHandlers = (
     ...
       {  LSHandlerContentType = "com.vallettaventures.texpadm.tex";
          LSHandlerPreferredVersions = { LSHandlerRoleAll = "-"; };
          LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.vallettaventures.texpad";
       },
       {  LSHandlerContentTag = "cfg";
          LSHandlerContentTagClass = "public.filename-extension";
          LSHandlerPreferredVersions = { LSHandlerRoleAll = "-"; };
          LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.apple.textedit";
       },
     ...
     );
  }
  ```

Unfortunately, none of these approaches have worked.

---

**System:** I am running macOS 11.3.1 on an Intel MacBook Air.