# Using Terminal commands, how can I find the application associated with a given file?

Tags: macos, command-line

Basically, what is the equivalent to

`what_is_associated call_diagram.dot.svg`

which would return some "pointer" back to the Vivaldi app on my system.

See below for what does the job graphically:

[image]

I did see some related questions:

[bash - List of file types and default Ubuntu applications to open with - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912370/list-of-file-types-and-default-ubuntu-applications-to-open-with)

- xdg-utils didn't seem to work after installing with macports, so that's out.

[Where does Mac OS X store file association information?](https://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information)

- That's a really old question, some of the utilities don't have the same path anymore and none of the answers were very informative about getting an exact result.

For what it's worth, I want it because some of my files are associated with VS Code and some with Sublime Text.  Under some conditions I also get provided a line number and the syntax to specify it is different:

- Sublime: `subl <filename>:<linenum>`
- VS Code: `code <filename>:<linenum> -g`

Answer (score 1):

The system wide application to file extension mappings is handled by the Launch Services process in modern versions of macOS. Based on this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91522/change-file-association-in-terminal) I think you might be able to just parse the associated plist file to find the associations you're looking for.

Comment: An example on how to parse the plist to find the relevant information would be useful.