# List extensions that are opened with a specific application

Tags: macos, file-extensions

Is there an easy way to find all the extensions that are opened with a given application?
I'm asking because I have two versions of a software installed (Sublime 2 and 3), and some extensions still open with Sublime 2 because by the time I specified that Sublime 3 was not available. I then have to quit Sublime, change the program that shall be opened by default for this extension and relaunch.

I would like to end this once and for all and change it for every remaining extension. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: In terminal, execute `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices.plist >> ~/Desktop/defaults.txt`. Open up the text file and find the keys matching each sublime property list. Once identified, you can set those opening with 2 to open with 3. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal)

Comment: @nijbot: Thanks for the tip, it brought me on the right track. When I execute your command, it returns an error "Domain com.apple.LaunchServices.plist does not exist". However, there is an additional file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`, that I opened with Xcode. You can change the default programs there.

Comment: you're welcome. there's not a simple way at all (AFAIK, or at least from what I looked into) to return the desired information using commands like `grep` `sed` or `awk` since you're matching multiple strings over multiple lines. The easiest way, as you note, is in Xcode. Also, not sure why `secure` is prepended to the extension, perhaps this is the behavior if you use filevault and your drive is encrypted (I don't), but that's the same file for sure. BOL. Cheers.

Comment: Also, why do you have both versions installed? Uninstalling Sublime 2 and then manually removing it's `.plist` would solve the immediate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.‌​plist` in Xcode. The file contains all the bindings for extensions to applications.

Find/replacing the values did not work for me, since the file was overwritten every time. But you can use Find to get a list of all the extensions that are opened with a particular application and then change it by hand.

Comment: In my original comment, follow the instructions in the link. You need to change these values using the terminal.

Comment: The problem is that the domain can not be found, thus I did not get it to work via Terminal.

Comment: edit the domain to `com.apple.launchservices.secure.‌​plist`

Comment: @njboot yes, I already tried that, same result. The weird thing about all this is that `default domains` actually does return `com.apple.LaunchServices`, even though the manpage specifically states that it only considers domains in the space of the user.

Comment: you may need `sudo` to edit the `plist` in that case, even though it's in your user library. Are you running filevault? Also, what happens if you `touch ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.plist; mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist ~/Desktop/`. Log out then in. does secure regenerate in your library? are you able to `defaults write` to the one you created?

Comment: [See this discussion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/why-is-a-command-line-change-to-library-preferences-com-apple-launchservices-p)

Comment: First of all, yes, I'm running FileVault. Second, `sudo` is not helping for the `secure` domain. I moved the `secure` file to the Desktop (it is, however, stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`), and as you assumed, it gets regenerated. I can write with `defaults write com.apple.launchservices.plist test 1` and then `defaults read` it afterwards, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all files with a certain extension (not the 1 specific file) to be opened by a certain app, do the following:

1. Right click the file and click `Get Info` (or highlight file and hit <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> )
2. Change `Open with:` to preferred app
3. Click `Change All...`
4. Click `Continue` in the confirmation box

Is this what you meant to do? This is different from right clicking a file and choosing the 'Always open with' option. That seems to only apply to the specific file, not all files globally.

You will have to repeat this for each extension.

[image: Get info screen]
[image: Confirmation box]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do know of this way. The problem is that I do not know which extensions are bound to Sublime 2.

Comment: Couldn't you simply 'override' all extensions you want opened with Sublime 3 using this method, once?

Comment: Sure, but I run the risk that I forget one and end up being annoyed later when I find one I forgot.