# How to make an app as default opener for particular file extension

Tags: macos, python, plist, gatekeeper

I am making an app in python named **cipherc** on mac osx 10.9 This app opens a file type of extension “**.secure**”

Now, in local system, for already present .**secure** file, its default file opener is some different xyz app. So, how can I make my app **cipherc** as default file opener for all .**secure** file extension present in system, **as soon as I installs cipherc app**.

My info.plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>cipherc</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>****</string>
                <string>fold</string>
                <string>disk</string>
            </array>    
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>secure</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>cipherc</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>cc.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.cipherc.macapp.cipherc</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>cipherc</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
    <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright not specified</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>PyMainFileNames</key>
    <array>
        <string>__boot__</string>
    </array>
    <key>PyOptions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>alias</key>
        <false/>
        <key>argv_emulation</key>
        <true/>
        <key>emulate_shell_environment</key>
        <false/>
        <key>no_chdir</key>
        <false/>
        <key>prefer_ppc</key>
        <false/>
        <key>site_packages</key>
        <false/>
        <key>use_faulthandler</key>
        <false/>
        <key>use_pythonpath</key>
        <false/>
        <key>verbose</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>PyResourcePackages</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
    <array>
        <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
        <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python</string>
    </array>
    <key>PythonInfoDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PythonExecutable</key>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <key>PythonLongVersion</key>
        <string>2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]</string>
        <key>PythonShortVersion</key>
        <string>2.7</string>
        <key>py2app</key>
        <dict>
            <key>alias</key>
            <false/>
            <key>template</key>
            <string>app</string>
            <key>version</key>
            <string>0.8</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically/Script-atically changing the default Open-With setting](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/programmatically-script-atically-changing-the-default-open-with-setting)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it manually, because Mavericks won't change the default app automatically, if there is already an app that can open .secure-files.

Follow these instructions and choose your script as app.

1. Find a file with an extension you want to change the defaults to.
   Right click on the file to see a menu, and select “Get Info”.
2. A window appears with the file’s information, see the section called “Open with”
3. It will display the current application used for this file, use the dropdown box to select you new application. You have to use the “Other” selection to browse for it.
4. Click on the “Change All” button to apply the change to all files ending with the same file extension.
5. That’s all.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to change it on install not how to do it manually for his own computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I make my app as default file opener for an extension while installation, with changes in info.plist,if there is no other app present for that file. Please see my info.plist

Comment: @imp ah I see. Check this answer for help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/programmatically-script-atically-changing-the-default-open-with-setting

Comment: @c0dev its not happening. can it be done through setting keys in info.plist file of app. It should happen while installation.

Answer (score 1):

This is asked and answered [over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal).  The short answer is Edit ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist.  For the long answer, click the link :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I make my app as default file opener for an extension while installation, with changes in info.plist,if there is no other app present for that file. Please see my info.plist.

Comment: Can it be done with keys setting in info.plist.